# Delete Item from List using Knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to delete an item from a list.  I am using knockout.js with the mapping plugin.  My code looks like this:

### Serialize to Json

```
@{ var jsonData = new HtmlString(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model));}
```

### Template

```
<script type="text/html" id="imgsList">
    {{each model.Imgs}}
        <div style="float:left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;">
            <div><a href="${Filename}"><img src="${Filename}" style="width:100px;"></img></a></div>
            <div data-bind="click: deleteImage">Delete</div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

### K.O. JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        //KO Setup
        var viewModel = { 
            "model": ko.mapping.fromJS(@jsonData),
            "deleteImage" : function(item) {alert(item.Filename + ' deleted.');}
        }

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

### The HTML

```
<div data-bind="template: 'imgsList'"></div>
```

### The Question

**Everything works as expected.  A list of images shows up with delete buttons, however, when you click a button item.Filename is undefined. Thoughts?**

Edit: Taken from the KNockout.js Manual: "When calling your handler, Knockout will supply the current model value as the first parameter. This is particularly useful if you’re rendering some UI for each item in a collection, and you need to know which item’s UI was clicked."

It appears that I am not getting back the Img object I am expecting.  I don't know what I am getting back!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use {{each}} syntax in jQuery Templates, the data context is whatever the overall template is bound against.  In your case, that is the entire view model.

A few options:

1- you can use your current code and pass the item that you are "eaching" on to the function like ( http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qB9tp/1/ ):

```
<div data-bind="click: function() { $root.deleteImage($value); }">Delete</div>
```

Using an anomymous function in the data-bind is pretty ugly though.  There are better options.

2- you can use the `foreach` parameter of the template binding, which works with jQuery Templates and is more efficient than {{each}} like ( http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qB9tp/2/ ):

```
<script type="text/html" id="imgsList">
    <div style="float:left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;">
        <div>
            <a href="${Filename}">${Filename}</a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="click: $root.deleteImage">Delete</div>
    </div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'imgsList', foreach: model.Imgs }"></div>
```

Now, the context of the template is the individual image object and calling `$root.deleteImage` will pass it as the first argument.

3- Since, the jQuery Templates plugin is deprecated and Knockout now supports native templates, you might want to choose removing your dependency on the jQuery Templates plugin.  You could still use a named template (just need to replace any jQuery Templates syntax with data-bind attributes) like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qB9tp/3/ or even remove the template and just go with the `foreach` control-flow binding like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qB9tp/4/

```
<div data-bind="foreach: model.Imgs">
    <div style="float:left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;">
        <div>
            <a data-bind="text: Filename, attr: { href: Filename }"></a>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="click: $root.deleteImage">Delete</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

4- While I prefer option #3, you could even choose to use event delegation and attach a "live" handler like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/qB9tp/5/

```
$("#main").on("click", ".del", function() {
   var data = ko.dataFor(this);
   viewModel.deleteImage(data); 
});
```

This can be especially beneficial if you would be attaching a large number of the same handlers via the `click` binding (like in a grid).

Comment: Amazing answer. I ended up with option 3.2 after reading about the deprecation of jquery.tmpl.  I didn't realized that KO had native support now though.  Glad I have all these options in my back pocket now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I notice there is an example of how to do this here:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/

Check out the **4. Cleaner event handling** section where Steve shows an example of an item being deleted from a list.

```
<h3>Products</h3>

<ul data-bind="foreach: products">
    <li>
        <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
        <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeProduct">Delete</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
    function appViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.products = ko.observableArray([
            { name: "XBox" },
            { name: "PlayStation" },
            { name: "Banana" },
            { name: "Wii" }
        ]);

        self.removeProduct = function(product) {
            self.products.remove(product);   
        }
    };

ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
```

But take into account that the above example is for KnockoutJS 2.0 which is the latest release.

Comment: Yea, it works like a champ when I do it like this.  The problem is that when I use templates it stops working.

Comment: It appears you are using jQuery templates, which does not act the same as native templates with KO. WHich did you want to use?

Comment: @Jason, you *ought* to use KO native templates. jquery.tmpl is a kind of dead-in-the-water tech, with no future updates planned.

Comment: I was wondering what to do because I read about jquery.tmpl being deprecated. Its still in the KO github so I figured the KO community was supporting it now or something.  Glad to find out KO has native support and I can just delete tmpl.